# Refresh specific line in a datasheet view in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in "Datasheet" mode in Access 2003 which can contains 25 000 lines.

When I want to edit a specific line, I open a specific form which contains all the editable field.

Once finished, I save and close the form but now I'd like to requery and refresh only the line I edited. (I want to keep the cursor at this line, and I'd like to avoid reloading every line so a requery on the form isn't the solution).

Is it possible ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think it is. You would have to requery your form, but you can put your cursor back where it was by saving the `AbsolutePosition` before you do so:

```
lngPos = Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition
Me.Requery
Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition = lngPos
```

By the way, I stole this idea from Albert D. Kallal on [pcreview](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/cursor-position-continuous-form-after-requery-t2861623.html). I have used the `Bookmark` object in the past, but it always seemed buggy.